# How To Group and Count 2 Different Types Like This?

Tags: mysql

I have table like this :

```
+-------------------+-------------+
| Items             | Status      |
+-------------------+-------------+
| 001               | Good        |
| 001               | Bad         |
| 001               | Good        |
| 002               | Good        |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

and I want to have output like this :

```
+-------------------+-------------+-------+
| Items             | Status      | Count |
+-------------------+-------------+-------+
| 001               | Good        | 2     |
| 001               | Bad         | 1     |
| 002               | Good        | 1     |
+-------------------+-------------+-------+
```

how to Group and Count table like that? that's all I need. thank you.

UPDATE :
I just realize that by having that output, I will have same rows on Items column. What if I want an output like this :

```
+-------------------+------+------+
| Items             | Bad  | Good |
+-------------------+------+------+
| 001               | 2    | 1    |
| 002               | 0    | 1    |
+-------------------+------+------+
```

is it possible doing it with MySQL? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: SELECT Items, Status, COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM MyTable GROUP BY Items, Status

Comment: podiluska : if I already tried and succeed, I won't be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   SELECT Items, Status, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
   FROM TableName
   GROUP BY Items, Status
```

Comment: thanks bro. I just knew that I can put more than one condition on GROUP BY. that's exactly what I need. accept as an answer in next 7 minutes ;-)